# Positive forms and strongly positive forms are bidual

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry, exterior-algebra

This question comes from the *Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry* by *Demailly*. Let $V$ be a $n$ dimensional complex space. Consider the exterior algebra $\Lambda V^* = \oplus \Lambda^{(p,q)}V^*$. $u \in \Lambda^{(q,q)}V^*$ is called strongly positive if
$$u= \sum \gamma_s i\alpha_{s,1} \wedge \bar{\alpha}_{s,1} \wedge \cdots \wedge i\alpha_{s,q}\wedge \bar{\alpha}_{s,q}$$
where $\gamma_s \ge 0$. $v \in \Lambda^{(p,p)}V^*$ where $p+q = n$ is called positive if $u\wedge v$ is positive $(n,n)$-form, i.e. $u\wedge v = \lambda i\mathrm{d}z_1 \wedge \mathrm{d}\bar{z}_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge i\mathrm{d}z_p \wedge \mathrm{d}\bar{z}_p$ where $\lambda$ is a real positive number, for all $u$ strongly positive.

The question comes whether $u$ is strongly positive if $u\wedge v$ is positive for all $v$ positive. In fact this is true in real case where bidual of a convex cone is its closure. This is also the fact that Demailly uses to prove the duality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is absolutely right.

The sets of positive and strongly positive forms are **closed** convex cones, i.e. closed and stable under convex combinations. Also, the positive cone  (**denoted by** $\Gamma_P$) is dual to the strongly positive cone (**denoted by** $\Gamma_{SP}$)  via the pairing

$$\Lambda^{p,p} V^*\times\Lambda^{q,q} V^*\longrightarrow \mathbb C$$
$$\qquad\quad(u,v)\qquad\quad\,\,\,\,\longmapsto u\wedge v\,/\,\tau,$$
where $\tau$ is the $(n,n)$-form determining the canonical orientation of $V$.
That is, $u\in\Lambda^{p,p}V^*$ is positive iff $u\wedge v\ge 0$ for all strongly positive forms $v\in\Lambda^{q,q} V^*.$

Using some knowledges from functional analysis, we know that the bidual of an arbitrary convex cone is equal to its closure. So, one has the following:
$$\begin{aligned} & v\,\,\text{is strongly positive} \\\iff & v\in\Gamma_{SP}\\\iff &v\in\,(\Gamma_{SP})^{**}\\\iff &v\in\,(\Gamma_P)^*\\\iff &\text{For all positive forms} \,\,u, \text{we have }v\wedge u=u\wedge v\ge 0. \end{aligned}$$

Comment: I actually wonder why bidual of an arbitrary convex cone is equal to its closure in complex vector space but with bidual in real sense, i.e. $A^\sharp=\{ x^* \in X^* : \langle x^*, x \rangle \ge 0 \forall x \in A \} $ where $X^*$ is the set of continuous complex functionals.

Comment: Maybe you can give an approachable reference.

Comment: For example, what do you mean by $(\Gamma_P)^*$

Comment: In common functional analysis theory, we can deal with $(\Gamma_P)^* = \{ x^* \in V^* : \mathrm{Re}(\langle x^* , x \rangle )  \ge 0 \}$. However we are now dealing with $(\Gamma_P)^* = \{ x^* \in V^* : \langle x^* , x \rangle  \ge 0 \}$

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. Sorry for ignoring that.  I can't see why now but I'll think about it.

Comment: @XTChen, what if we notice the fact that all positive forms, not to mention all strongly positive forms are real?

Comment: You are right! Case Closed!